# move uploaded file success but could not find file in folder

Tags: php, opencart

I have the following code

```
public function upload() {
    if($_FILES){
        $this->load->model('account/customer');
        $file = $_FILES['profile'];
        $file_name = $file['name'];
        // $ext = end(explode('.', $file_name));
        // $file_name = 'na_'.md5(time()).'.'.$ext;
        echo $file_content = $file['tmp_name'];
        $data = array('customer_id' => $this->customer->getId(), 'img_url' => $file['name']);
        $this->model_account_customer->profileImage($data);
        echo 'test/'.$file_name;
        $img = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], 'test/'.$file['name']);
        if($img) {
            $return = json_encode(array('status' => 1));
        } else {
            $return = json_encode(array('status' => 0));
        }
        echo $return;
    }
}
```

The above code returning `status` as `1` but could not see the file in folder.
I check folder permission is `0777`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending a `/` in front of the path

```
move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], '/test/'.$file['name']);
```

Comment: Tried no luck... Whats happening here

Comment: is the path correct? Where does the test folder resides?

Comment: for testing purpose I add a folder in `controller/account/test` and the file which has above function in `controller/account/customer.php`

Comment: move the test folder to root and check, in which controller admin or catalog

Comment: Ok If I need to upload image to `image/profile_image` how can I include it in  my above controller function

Comment: you just have to give the path starting from root until your desired folder. Keep in mind that the index.php file is executed all other files are included in it. So in your case `image/profile_image/$file['name']`